# Flash banner link not accessible in openX?

Tags: flash, actionscript, openx, clicktag

I make flash banners for different clients and all were happy until I met fellows who use openX  . I used the regular as2 code(they demanded as2)

```
on (release){
  getURL("http://www.ge.vtb.ge/personal/cards/credit/");
}
```

but they said it doesn't convert or something, so I found out I needed clicktag, I used this code

```
on (release) {
  if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:www.[mylink].com") {
    getURL(clickTAG,clickTARGET);
  }
}
```

as was stated in [this](http://www.openx.com/docs/tutorials/Using+Flash+with+OpenX) tutorial , but now they say the banner isn't linked. I'm really confused what to do, can anyone give me a suggestion? I even read through [adobes official guide for clicktag](http://www.adobe.com/resources/richmedia/tracking/designers_guide/) , but it was the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition here:

```
if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:www.[mylink].com")
```

will never resolve to `TRUE`, so the `getURL` will never be called. Please change it to:

```
if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:")
```

and check if its working now.

EDIT:

Make sure they are setting the clickTAG variable with the right URL when embedding the swf banner. I'll copy the relevant part of the [official clickTAG guide](http://www.adobe.com/resources/richmedia/tracking/designers_guide/):

*The code below will allow ad serving networks to dynamically assign a clickTAG to their ad.*

*In this example, a getURL action is being assigned to a button that will navigate the browser to ["clickTAG"]. The "getURL(clickTAG)" statement appends the variable data passed in via the OBJECT EMBED tag and navigates the browser to that location. It is the tracking code assigned by the ad serving network, which allows them to register a user's click on that advertisement.*

```
<EMBED src="ad_banner_example.swf?clickTAG= http://adnetwork.com/tracking?http://www.destinationURL.com">
```

This would be the workflow, I think you guys are skipping the 3rd step (passing the URL to the swf object):

[image: clickTAG workflow]

Comment: but how do I link the banner then?

Comment: I changed the condition, but now The client says that the banner is navigating her to a blank page...

Comment: yes it helped a lot, they really were skipping the third step and had to teach my client how to use openX. thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note that you don't actually have to write the embed code for the ad, or hard-code the clickTAG URL in OpenX.  Instead choose the "**Upload banner to local webserver**" (or database).  This gives OpenX the opportunity to "read" the file and determine how to proceed.

If the URL is hard-coded into the file, OpenX can find it, and track clicks that way.  If the URL is being expected as a clickTAG variable, the normal "**Destination URL (incl. http://)**" will be passed into the ad as the clickTAG FlashVars variable.

I hope that helps someone!

Here's are links to OpenX's articles on this issue:

http://www.openx.dev.limusdesign.com/blog/click-tracking-flash-banners/

which links to the full help article here (now missing from the live site, but found in the Wayback Machine):

http://web.archive.org/web/20130315080057/http://www.openx.com/docs/tutorials/Using+Flash+with+OpenX